# How to async/await on firebase.auth().currentUser?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, firebase-authentication

I am using ReactJs, and defined a `Route` which will load `<Loans />`component if the path is `mywebsite.com/loans`. Below is the code snippet for the `<Loans />`component. In the `componentDidMount`, I have `async/await` to get the `currentUser` from `firebase`. If `user` is `null`, page will be redirected to `/signin` page.

```
class Loans extends Component {
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      this.props.history.push("/signin");
    }
  };
  render () {
  ...}
}
```

Here is the code snippet for `<SignIn />`component. In `SignIn` component, there is a listener to listen any auth state change, if user is logged in, page will be redirected to `/loans`page.

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.props.history.push("/loans");
      }
    });
  }

  render () {
    ...
  }
}
```

I actually already logged in. But I observed a weird behavior that whenever I refreshed the page `/loans`, page will be redirected to `/signin` page for less than a second and then quickly redirected back to `/loans` page.

My question is if I already have `firebase.auth().currentUser` to be `async/await`, how could I still get `null` for the `user` in `<Loans />` component, and I only see `<Loans />` component when the page is redirected from `<SignIn />` page? How can I aviod to see the SignIn page if I already have user logged in in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firebase.auth().currentUser` isn't a promise, it's a User object, so using `await` on it doesn't make much sense.  According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#currentuser), it's only going to be a User object, or null.  It will be null when there is no user signed in, or the User object just isn't available yet.

What you should be doing instead is using the same style of listener in SignIn to determine when a User object is ready, and render any content only after that listener indicates a User is present.

Comment: Thanks Doug! But for onAuthStateChanged, if I never received an User object, how can I tell it's user not logged in or it's because the process take a bit longer? Because I need to know whether I need to redirect to SignIn page if it's because user not logged in.

Comment: You should be using the listener to determine when the user is signed in.  That is the provided mechanism.  It doesn't matter how long it takes the sign in to complete - the listener will be invoked.

Comment: I adjust my code based upon your suggestion and it worked. Thanks Doug and happy holidays!

Comment: @damingzi it would be helpful if you can post the solution, I know it's almost 2 years back :D

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a HOC to handle this. Quick example below

```
import React from "react"
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth } from "./firebase" // Where to store firebase logic
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth)

  if (loading) {
    return <></>
  } else if (user?.uid && !loading) {
    return children
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }
}
```

Then in the router (I'm using RR v6) you just wrap the page component in the hoc.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={
    <RequireAuth>
      <Dashboard />
    </RequireAuth>
  }
/>
```

You could also extract this out to a hook and call it in every page instead of at the router level but I feel like this is a bit more readable as far as seeing which routes are protected. This also follows the example of protected routes in the RR docs.