# React Navigate to page based on useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using GoTrue-JS to authenticate users on a Gatsby site I'm working on and I want the homepage to route users to either their user homepage or back to the login page.

I check the existence of a logged-in user in a Context layer then define a state (user) that is evaluated on the homepage with a useEffect hook with the state as the dependency.

The expected behavior is that the useEffect hook will trigger the check for a user once the function is completed and route the user. But what happens is that the hook seems to check without the user state getting changed which routes the user to the login page.

Here's an abridged version of the code:

context.js

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
} from "react";
import GoTrue from 'gotrue-js';
export const IdentityContext = createContext();
const IdentityContextProvider = (props) => {
  //create the user state
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  //init GoTrue-JS 
  const auth = useMemo(() => {
    return new GoTrue({
      APIUrl: "https://XXXXXX.netlify.app/.netlify/identity",
      audience: "",
      setCookie: true,
    });
  },[]);

  //get the user if they are signed in
  useEffect(() => { 
    setUser(auth.currentUser());
  },[auth]);
 

  return (
    <IdentityContext.Provider value={{ auth,user }}>
      {props.children}
    </IdentityContext.Provider>
  )
  
}
export default IdentityContextProvider;
```

index.js

```
import { navigate } from 'gatsby-link';
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { IdentityContext } from '../contexts/IdentityContext';

export default function HomePage() {
  const { user } = useContext(IdentityContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      navigate("/user/home");
      console.log("there's a user");   
    } else {
      navigate("/login");
      console.log("no user");
    }
  }, [user]);

  return null
}
```

When I remove the navigate functions I see no user, then there's a user in the log when I load the homepage. I thought the useEffect hook would only fire if the state I listed in the dependency array (`user`) was changed. If there's no user then `auth.currentUser()` will return null and if there is one, then I will get all the user data.

Comment: I noticed if I make the currentUser() function within the useEffect  and don't import the user state from my context layer I wont get that double trigger but I'm still at a loss how useEffect would trigger without the dependency changing.

Comment: I'm not sure how the auth is working, but I think the useMemo should be useCallback.  Since the memo doesn't depend on anything, the _result_ never changes.  I suspect on first render, there's no user, so that is locked-in.  I don't see where the user is defined or handed to the auth function, either.

Comment: auth initializes the Netlify Identity client: https://github.com/netlify/gotrue-js#usage. If I convert to useCallback, then the call fails since it appears that new GoTrue is more of a value than a function. I did useMemo so I wouldn't get warnings, but it can just be stored as a const

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the user as a dependency? Just use the useEffect with an empty dependency. Also if you want to block the view while the processing, make a state as isLoading ( bool) and conditional render with it

```
!isLoading ?
   <></>
  :
   <h1>Loading..</h1>
```

Comment: user is a dependency because I need to see if the user is logged in. if I remove the dependency then I get the following warning: ` React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'user'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` and then it doesn't detect the user

Comment: also, if your question starts "why are you..." my evergreen answer will I don't know what I'm doing and it's why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: Netlify's gotrue-js will return `null` for currentUser() if there is no user signed in so I need to first declare my user state as something other than `null` then set my conditional to detect `null` specifically so my app knows the check for a signed in user occurred.

context.js

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
} from "react";
import GoTrue from 'gotrue-js';
export const IdentityContext = createContext();
const IdentityContextProvider = (props) => {
  //create the user state
  //set either to empty string or undefined
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  
  //init GoTrue-JS 
  const auth = useMemo(() => {
    return new GoTrue({
      APIUrl: "https://XXXXXX.netlify.app/.netlify/identity",
      audience: "",
      setCookie: true,
    });
  },[]);

  //get the user if they are signed in
  useEffect(() => { 
    setUser(auth.currentUser());
  },[auth]);
 

  return (
    <IdentityContext.Provider value={{ auth,user }}>
      {props.children}
    </IdentityContext.Provider>
  )
  
}
export default IdentityContextProvider;
```

index.js

```
import { navigate } from 'gatsby-link';
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { IdentityContext } from '../contexts/IdentityContext';

export default function HomePage() {
  const { user } = useContext(IdentityContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      navigate("/user/home");
      console.log("there's a user");   
    } else if (user == null) {
      navigate("/login");
      console.log("no user");
    }
  }, [user]);

  return null
}
```

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472380/how-to-async-await-on-firebase-auth-currentuser) regarding Firebase where they were also getting no user on load even when one was signed in because of the state. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472482/3411192) is doesn't provide a snippet so it's gone to the wisdom of the ancients, but I was able to work with  another engineer to get this solution.